# what does this forkjoinreuse and forkjoindeeprecursive mean?

Tags: java, fork-join, jmh

I have been trying to understand [this micro-benchmark](https://github.com/shipilev/disrupting-fjp/tree/master/src/main/java/net/shipilev).

In the source there are four types of ForkJoin: `ForkJoinreuse` and `ForkJoinrecursivedeep`. I don't understand in which way they are different from `ForkJoin` and `ForkJoinrecursive`, even when I have read the sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these two classes it looks as if there is a precision difference:

ForkJoinRecursive.java versus ForkJoinRecursiveDeep

      
'if (slices < 10000)'  versus 'if (slices <= 1)'

Overall it appears that the code is trying to use concurrency, i.e. implement multiple threads. Check out the links below for more information.

[Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
[Processes and Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)